# Cannon see subcategory in permalink

Tags: categories, permalinks

There are a lot of articles (old one, though because I use new WordPress 5.3.1) about how to include category and subcategory in WordPress URLs. I followed those articles (pretty much are the same), but something is wrong.

I checked Settings > Permalinks > Custom Structure and added `/%category%/%postname%/`, and all I can see is parent category, not child category.

It's the same issue whatever template I use, so I guess template is not a problem.

What is wrong?

Comment: Please assign only child category so it will display parent and child category in URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

WordPress determines the permalink by finding the category closest to the root.

- If the parent category is selected (or if both the parent category and the child category are selected), then the permalink will only include the parent category.
- If only the child category is selected, then the permalink will include the parent category followed by the child category.

So, for your case, be sure to select only the child category.

Comment: Yes, when I select only child, permalink shows both, parent and child. But what I did, first, I selected only child (than saved), than selected parent (child is already selected) and saved - permalink shows both, parent and child. Looks like a bug...